# How does git fetch determine which objects the client is missing?

Tags: git

I always wondered how `git fetch` determines which objects need to be transfered. The client cannot decide it since it doesn't know which objects belong to the branch and the server cannot decide it since it doesn't know which objects the client already has.

I read that the client sends its current state of the branch it wants to fetch and the server derives from that which commits it is still missing, but I think that doesn't totally eliminate the possibility of unnecessary object transmissions. For example consider those two repos:

client:

```
    b1  b2
    |   |
    v   v
A - B - C
```

server:

```
        b2  b1
        |   |
        v   v
A - B - C - D
```

Now if the client fetches branch `b1` requesting all new commits since commit `B`, `C` is transmitted even though it is already known to the client. More complicated and devastating examples could be constructed.

Is this neglected or is there some clever solution to it that I am missing. Is there an in-depth description of git's fetch mechanism? Also, is there any academic literature about such problems? ("DAG replication/synchronization" maybe?)

**Edit:** I tested the example above and when fetching `b1`, there are less objects transfered, if `b2` is already fetched. So there seems to be more to it then just "Give me everything for b1 since B".

Comment: For a pure information-theoretic approach plus a little practical, see [chapter 4 of this rather incomplete work-in-progress](http://web.torek.net/torek/tmp/book.pdf). For how Git specifically does it, see the book linked in [Michał Zaborowski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48132758/1256452).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found at [git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols):

> [...] the `fetch-pack` process looks at what objects it has and responds with the objects that it needs by sending “want” and then the SHA-1 it wants. It sends all the objects it already has with “have” and then the SHA-1. At the end of this list, it writes “done” to initiate the `upload-pack` process to begin sending the packfile of the data it needs:
>
> ```
> 003cwant ca82a6dff817ec66f44342007202690a93763949 ofs-delta
> 0032have 085bb3bcb608e1e8451d4b2432f8ecbe6306e7e7
> 0009done
> 0000
> ```

(where `upload-pack` is the process on the server side)

So if I get this right, the client includes a list of *all* objects it already knows in the request, which seems pretty inefficient. But there seems to be no better solution as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) is good book about git. Under the hood, it is file system. Each commit is set of objects - directories, and files. Each commit contains whole data, not difference, like in CVS/SVN. However if something was not changed, can be referenced from different places. So it is quite optimal.

Answering your question. Client sends last synced version of fetched branch... That way server knows the difference. That difference is set of commits, and rest is already described... Hope it helps.